# Examples for a contractible pair that induce a non-surjective fundamental groups homomorphism.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

In Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, **Proposition 1.17** says that

> If a connected $X$ retracts onto a connected subspace $A$, the inclusion $i:A\hookrightarrow X$ induce a injective map $i_*:\pi_1(A)\to\pi_1(X)$. If $X$ can deformation retract to $A$, then $i_*$ is a isomorphism.

If the $X$ can retract but not deformation retract onto $A$, is the surjective of $i_*$ still holds?

The zigzag space, example in **Exercise 0.6**, has trivial fundamental group so it doesn't give the counterexample.

What about the weak contractible property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any product $A \times B$ will give a retract down to either factor once you pick a basepoint in the other.  If both factors have interesting fundamental groups then the induced map will be injective but not surjective as it won't be iso.

Additional details...

Take $A$ and $B$ to be connected spaces and fix a point $b \in B$.  Define a map $f: A \times B \rightarrow A \times \{b\}$ by $f= \mathrm{id}_A \times b$, so $f(x,y) = (x, b)$.  This is clearly continuous and it clearly fixes the subspace $A \times \{b\}$ pointwise.  Thus $f$ is a retract.  For most examples the induced-inclusion $i_*: \pi_1(A) \to \pi_1(A\times B)$ probably isn't onto. For example, take $A=\mathbb{R}$ and $B=S^1$.

Comment: No, you can't retract $\mathbb R\times \mathbb S^1$ to $\mathbb R\times\{1\}$, it is not projection.

Comment: Sure you can.  You collapse the cylinder down to its seam line. This leaves the seam fixed so it's a retract.

Comment: If you don't believe me, then map the circle to one of its points by a necessarily constant map.  This is a retract but the induced map by the inclusion definitely isn't onto.

Comment: I mean a continuous homotopy map $f_t(x):X\times[0,1]\to X,$ such that $f_0=id$ and $f_1(X)\subset A$, a circle cannot homotopically deform to be a point.

Comment: I'm answering the retraction part not being onto, not the deformation retract question.   You asked "If the $X$ can retract but not deformation retract onto $A$, is the surjective of $i_*$ still holds?"

Comment: Are we meaning different things by "retract"?  My meaning is here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retract

Comment: You're right, I am sorry that I mistake the concept.

Comment: It is okay.  I have a PhD in homotopy theory and I still have to look up the definitions of deformation and strong deformation retract when I need them.